# Can a single random variable have a covariance matrix?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, covariance, optimal-transport

[This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Normal_distributions) about the closed-form analytical solution for the Wasserstein distance says:

> Let $\mu_1\in \mathbb{R}^N$ be a normally distributed random variable with expected value $m_1$ and covariance matrix $C_1$.

I never knew there could be a covariance matrix for univariate data, only multivariate data. How is it possible for a single random variable to have a covariance matrix?

Answer (score 3):

The random variable $\mu_1$ is in $\mathbb{R}^N$, so it's an $N$ dimensional vector.  The covariance matrix for it would be the covariance matrix between each of the components of $\mu_1$.

Comment: so covariance between each of its $N$ sample observations?

Comment: I don't think you're taking multiple samples here?  $\mu_1$ is a single sample from the multivariate normal distribution.  It's the same idea as if you take $X$ to be a normally distributed random variable with mean 0 and variance 1: There's only one sample, so you can't really talk about the variance of sample observations, but it still makes sense to say $X$ has variance 1.  Here, we have $\mu_1 = (\mu_1^{(1)},\mu_1^{(2)},...,\mu_1^{(N)})$ is a single multivariate random variable and $(C_1)_{ij}$ is the covariance between the components $\mu_1^{(i)}$ and $\mu_1^{(j)}$

Comment: $\mu_1$ is a random variable. now you're saying $\mu_1$ is a single sample, so a point, which contradicts with what you also say of $\mu_1$ being a vector. Let's get something straight: when I say "sample observation" I don't mean a sample from a multivariate, which is a univariate vector. I mean "an observation (point) from a random variable/vector's sample set". You still seem to be confusing this all to be multivariate when it in fact is univariate. but then suddenly at the end you switch gears and say "components" which looks to me what I mean by "sample observations"

Comment: I don't think $N$ is the *number of random variables*. there is only one random variable, so $N$ must be  the *number of observations* in the (univariate) sample

Comment: There isn't a contradiction there; a random variable can have multiple dimensions.  What do you mean by a "univariate vector"?  A sample from a multivariate normal on $\mathbb{R}^N$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$.  There is a single random variable, which is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$.  A vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$ has $N$ components, and if you wanted to think of them as $N$ separate random variables that would be fine too.  Where are you getting that it is univariate from?  The article explicitly says it's a Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I am *not* thinking of them as separate random variables. *Again*, what you are calling "components" corresponds with what I am calling "sample observations". An $N$ shaped vector *is* univariate data. Since we agree on that, how can you possibly construct a covariance matrix of a univariate dataset?

Answer (score 1):

A covariance matrix is something which exists for any random *vector*, where a random vector is nothing more than $N$ random variables which are possibly correlated. Since $\mu_1\in \mathbb R^N$, $\mu_1$ is a random vector, and has a covariance matrix. Specifically, each realization of $\mu_1$ is some vector:
$$
(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N),
$$
and the $(i,j)$ entry of the covariance matrix are $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=E[X_iX_j]-E[X_i]E[X_j]$, for $i,j\in \{1,\dots,N\}$.

In the other answer, you seem to be saying that there cannot be a covariance matrix, since "there is only one random variable." However, I would say that there are $N$ random variables. Just like a vector in $\mathbb R^N$ has $N$-coordinates, so $N$ real numbers, a *random vector* in $\mathbb R^n$ will have $N$ random variables as coordinates. You seem to be referring to these as "sample observations," but that seems to gloss over the fact that the coordinates may be correlated.

Let us specialize to $N=2$ for a second. Just like a continuous random variable in one dimension should be thought of in terms of its pdf, which is a function defined on $\mathbb R^1$, a random vector in $\mathbb R^2$ should be thought of in terms of its pdf, which is a function defined on the plane $\mathbb R^2$. Here is an example of such a pdf for a normal distribution. Each realization of this random vector is some ordered pair of points, like $(52, 45)$, which gives rise to two random variables, $X_1=52$ and $X_2=45$. The numbers $52$ and $45$ are not different sample observations; they are coordinates of the same single sample observation. These two coordinate may have different means and variances; in the picture, the $X$ coordinate of that distribution has a mean of around $50$, while the $Y$ coordinate has a means near $40$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you have single random variable $(X)$ then this variable is described by mean $E(X)$, and $VAR(X)$. However, if you two random variables $(XY)$ then the mean is $E(X)E(Y)$ and the $COV(XY)$ is the covariance matrix. The diagonal elements of this 2x2 matrix (since we have two random variable $(XY)$ we have 2x2 covariance matrix), is the $VAR(X)$ and $VAR(Y)$. Now $μ ∈ R^N$ has N components it's a vector, implies $μ = [μ1, μ2, ...μN]^T$. We will have NxN covariance matrix $C1$.